# DropDownCheckBoxes Not Responding To Bootstrap Class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm using DropDOwnCheckBox as one of my controls in a ASP.NET page. Each time i try using the form-control class from Bootstrap, I get no response.This is my code:

```
     <cc1:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddlChkBoxLst" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Visible="False" UseSelectAllNode="False" AddJQueryReference="true">
                                    <%--<Style SelectBoxWidth="195" DropDownBoxBoxWidth="160" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="90"></Style>--%>
                                        <Items>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Bank" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Sector" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Country" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Investment Type" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Location" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="By Amount" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </Items>
                                </cc1:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

Before, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Bootstrap Dropdown-checkbox" for implementing dropdown with checkbox.

All you nedd to do this as below:-

Installation

1. Add jQuery and Bootstrap.
2. Add this after HTML body and jQuery:-

   script type"text/javascript" src="/path/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.js"
3. Add this after the  section:

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
>   href="/path/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox.css">

The HTML template you should use:

```
div class="myDropdownCheckbox"
```

Then, through a jQuery selector:

```
var myData = [{id: 1, label: "Test" }];
$(".myDropdownCheckbox").dropdownCheckbox({
  data: myData,
  title: "Dropdown Checkbox"
});
```

For more details:http://acquisio.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox/